# Using multiple threads with the console

Tags: c, multithreading, console

I am using pthreads to create an multithreaded application (in this case a chat client - that mostly works, actually.)

The problem I have is that I have one thread trying to read and the other thread trying to print to the same console window.

For example if the user types in `something` to the console, but receives a message from the other thread, `another`, he could be looking at `somethinganother` - but when he presses enter the only data he submits is `something`!

Could anyone be so kind as to tell me how to deal with this?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, the thread who print write on stdout and when the user write with is keyboard it's on stdin. Do you want to display the text in differents areas ?

Comment: You might like to have look at this: http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/

Comment: Try to use semaphores. From what you have stated; I can understand that maybe it is a synchronization problem.

Comment: Please be more specific about what the desired behavior is.  The input thread is always reading, and the user may type several characters and then forget to type "enter" for many hours.  So when do you want the program to output "another" to stdout?